# visual studio reference icons

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

B"H

A while ago some of the references in my ASP 5 (.nt 461) project started showing up with new icons. [image: Reference Icons] Most of these references are packages that I added with Nuget. Yet some of them were references added years ago by the new project template. Many of them are no longer showing up when I "Manage Nuget Packages"

I ignored them at first, but now I am getting all kinds of package not found errors. So I am trying to figure out what these mean, in my attempt to track down the culprits. I haven't been able to find any documentation on them

Comment: the icon just means that it couldn't find the packages in your project references now. But the real issue is that it met some compiled error or reference error after you update the old project to higher VS versions. You have to check that whether it works well in old VS version, and make sure that whether certain assembly has been updated or replaced by other packages or we couldn't update it directly using the higher VS(Maybe the VS forget to install certain packages or others).

Comment: What does the yellow one meen and what does the blue one meen? Whats the difference?

Comment: AFAIK, the yellow one mean this assembly is managed by dll file directly, the blue one means this assembly managed by nuget.